# which one is the best solution for ROW > CONTAINER 15px margin in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have read many questions about this issue.
And also read some comments, but not solutions to fix this issue.
Can you tell me how can I use effectively Row Divs within a container without having the extra margin of 15px? I dont want to hardcode the css file of bootstrap to get rid of the  problem?

here is the link to my SITE issue. [image](http://i62.tinypic.com/24bm5oi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Customize your bootstrap download, specifically changing the less variable `@grid-gutter-width`. By default this variable is set to `30px`, so `15px` for both the right and left side.

> 30px : Padding between columns. Gets divided in half for the left and right.

If you go to the [Bootstrap Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#less-variables) page, you can edit the `less-variables` and download a custom compiled version of bootstrap that fits your needs. Also, if you do it this way, you don't have to manually edit `bootstrap.css`, which you shouldn't do anyway.

Comment: I didn't take the time to customize a download , and looking in this matter I should spend time  digging in .  Txs

Comment: Yeah. The nice thing about bootstrap is you can customize pretty much everything. If you want, try this link too: http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/ You can customize the variable and see their changes in real time. Quite useful.